# Getting the currently open file in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a command in the `vscode` namespace that allows you to get the `TextDocument` instance for the currently open file? I found `vscode.workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument`, but it doesn't work for files that are open on launch

Answer (score 15):

A few options depending on your needs:

```
// Single active editor. Editors have a `.document` property
vscode.window.activeTextEditor

// All showing text editors. For a split view, there are two active editors 
vscode.window.visibleTextEditors

// All open documents that vscode knows about. Do not have to be showing
vscode.workspace.textDocuments
```

See the vscode API for more info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api

Comment: Thx, it helped :)

Comment: I want to have printed to the terminal the file location of the currently opened file in editor. Can I get the info for a command from the api you linked ? Example: I have a config file of an extension that I want to share. I see the location hovering over the tab in the editor and in the breadcrumb. I want to have this location string for copying it.

Comment: What about in 2023? I opened devtools but `vscode.window` is already undefined.

Comment: @kungfooman The vscode apis don't work in the VS Code window's devtools, only in an extension

Answer (score 1):

If current active editor is a custom editor(with `registerCustomEditorProvider()`), `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` could not get the right information.

You could try `vscode.window.tabGroups.activeTabGroup.activeTab.input`, which has following properties `{ viewType: string; uri: vscode.Uri; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are interested in `${file}` for task. This script tests the currently active file

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "command": [
        "clear &&",
        "node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage ${file}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/backend"
      },
      "group": "test",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "npm: test - backend - current file",
      "detail": "NODE_ENV=test jest"
    }
  ]
}
```